# Написать код организовать обрабатывающий запросы с очередями к 2 обрабатывающим процессорам. Поток запросов пуассоновский со средним значением 1,5 с

Tags: моделирование

Задание: «В условиях разобранного примера организовать обработку запросов с различными очередями к 2 обрабатывающим процессорам. Поток запросов пуассоновский со средним значением 1,5 с. Также нужно предположить, что работа накопителя на жестком диске требует вмешательства процессора.»

Simulate
GENERATE 75,25
QUEUE 1,1
SEIZE PROC
ADVANCE 1,0
DEPART 1,1
RELEASE PROC
TERMINATE 1

B1 SEIZE MEMORY
MEM STORAGE 100
ENTER MEM,2
GATE SNF MEM,OUT
LEAVE MEM
RELEASE MEMORY
OUT TERMINATE 1

GENERATE 75,25
QUEUE 2,1
SEIZE HARDDRIVE
ADVANCE 120,25
ADVANCE 10,5
RELEASE HARDDRIVE
TRANSFER ,B1
start 100
;end

Условие кода который нужно изменить

Информационная система реального времени состоит из центрального процессора (ЦП), основной памяти (ОП) емкостью
100 Кбайт и накопителя на жестком диске (ЖД). Запросы от большого
числа удаленных терминалов поступают каждые 75 ± 25 мс и обрабатываются ЦП за время 1 мс. После этого каждый запрос помещается в ОП либо
получает отказ в обслуживании, если ОП заполнена (каждый запрос занимает 2 Кбайта памяти). Для обслуживаемых запросов производится поиск
информации на ЖД за время 120 ± 25 мс и ее считывание за время 10±5 мс.
Работа с ЖД не требует вмешательства ЦП. После этого запрос считается
обслуженным и освобождает место в ОП. Требуется смоделировать процесс обслуживания 100 запросов. Подсчитать число запросов, получивших
отказ в обслуживании. Определить содержимое ОП, а также коэффициент
загрузки ЖД.

Comment: Хорошая задача. А в чем вопрос?

Comment: В условиях разобранного примера организовать обработку запросов с различными очередями к 2 обрабатывающим процессорам. Поток запросов пуассоновский со средним значением 1,5 с. Также нужно предположить, что работа накопителя на жестком диске требует вмешательства процессора. Изменить код согласно условию.

Comment: Это не вопрос, это задание. Попробуйте сделать сами, и задайте конкретный вопрос, когда у вас что-то не получится.

Comment: Наверное не получается, раз спрашиваю.